# Writing 4:2:0 YUV-Rawdata into an AVI-File via DirectShow in C++

Tags: c++, video, directshow, avi

I'm trying to write some 4:2:0 rawdata received from a capture card into an AVI-File. For every pixel the char buffer contains 2 Bytes (16 Bit). The order of the data is the same as FOURCC UYVY: YUV 4:2:2 (Y sample at every pixel, U and V sampled at every second pixel horizontally on each line). A macropixel contains 2 pixels in 1 u_int32.

First I tried the OpenCV Videowriter. But this is simply too slow for this huge amount of video data (I'm capturing 2 video streams, each is 1080p25 format), so I switched to the "Video for Windows"-Library by Windows. But even this one does't proceed the file writing in real time. My last chance is Directshow. I want to use the AVI Mux and the File Writer Filters to store my raw data as an AVI-File, but I'm not shure how to "give" the AVI Mux my raw data (char array) which contains just video data in UYVY-order and no audio. Maybe you can give me an advice. This is what I've got until now:

```
CoInitialize(NULL);
    IGraphBuilder*pGraph= NULL;
    CoCreateInstance(CLSID_FilterGraph, NULL,CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER,IID_IGraphBuilder, (void **)&pGraph);

    IMediaControl*pMediaControl= NULL;
    pGraph->QueryInterface(IID_IMediaControl,(void **)&pMediaControl);

    ICaptureGraphBuilder2 *pCapture= NULL;
    CoCreateInstance(CLSID_CaptureGraphBuilder2, NULL,CLSCTX_INPROC,IID_ICaptureGraphBuilder2, (void **)&pCapture);

    IBaseFilter *pMux;
    pCapture->SetOutputFileName(&MEDIASUBTYPE_Avi,L"Test.avi",&pMux,NULL); 

    IBaseFilter *pCap;
    pCapture->RenderStream(&PIN_CATEGORY_CAPTURE, &MEDIATYPE_Video,pCap,NULL,pMux);
```

Thx a lot and Regards,

Valentin

Answer (score 0):

(As you mentioned 10 fps in previous question, which I assume to be effective frame rate) Are you writing dual 1920x1080 12 bits per pixel 10 fps into a file? This is 60 megabytes per second, you might be just hitting your HDD writing capacity limit.

Choosing different API is not going to help if your HDD is not powerful enough. You need to either compress data, or lower resolution or FPS. Or use faster drives.

Comment: Sometimes simple solutions are the best ^^. Thx a lot. Using a RAID solves the problem. Regards